# Normal vs Log normal implied volatility

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility

I am referring to an earlier discussion at [How do we know if the volatility which is quoted in market is Normal (Bachelier model) or log normal (Black 76)?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21483/how-do-we-know-if-the-volatility-which-is-quoted-in-market-is-normal-bachelier)

For the short rate case, is there any **approximate relation between these 2 types of volatilities**, given that we have quote for `log-normal`.

Comment: Hi, I think this thread can help you: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27795/transforming-log-return-volatility-into-standard-return-volatility . Let us know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pat Hagan describes this well in the famous SABR paper [Managing smile risk](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjpws_4kafsAhXNGuwKHYWTAHIQFjABegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F235622441_Managing_Smile_Risk&usg=AOvVaw32CjZWtFtniNkLAErsOPSK). An approximate relation given in equation (B.64) reads
$$\sigma_N \approx \sigma_B \frac{f-K}{\ln f/K}\left(1-\frac{\sigma_B^2 T}{24}\right),$$
where $\sigma_N$ is the normal (or Bachelier) vol, $\sigma_B$ is the Black-Scholes volatility, $f$ is the forward price, $T$ the option time to maturity, and $K$ the option strike.
In particular, at-the-money, we have $\sigma_N \approx \sigma_B f$.

There exists [very fast algorithms](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2420757) which allow to convert a Black vol to a normal (or b.p. vol) vol with near machine epsilon accuracy. They start from an option price, you would just use the Black-Scholes formula with $\sigma_B$ to obtain it.

Comment: Thanks. One question though. What is the unit of $f$ in above equation? Is it expressed as absolute value like $0.05$ or expressed as percentage $5$ in case my forward short rate is `5%`? Also, from the equation, it appears that, $\sigma_N < \sigma_B$. But from the bloomberg quotes in the link of my original post, this inequality does not seem to hold always. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is because in Bloomberg, Black vols are expressed in %, and normal vols in basis points. In the formula the units are the natural units, so $f=0.05$, $\sigma_B$ = 0.5 for 50% and $\sigma_N = 0.005$ for 50 b.p.

Answer (score 2):

**Choi et al (2022)** have a slightly better approximation for the volatility conversion:

**Eq. (17):**
$$\sigma_N(K) \approx \sigma_B F_0 \sqrt{k}\left(1+\frac{\log^2 k}{24}\right) \Big/ \left(1 + \frac{\sigma_B^2}{24} T \right) \;\;\text{for}\;\; k=\frac{K}{F_0}.
$$
is better than **Eq. (16)** which from Grunspan (2011):
$$\sigma_N(K) \approx \sigma_B F_0 \frac{k-1}{\log k} \left(1 - 
\log \left(\frac{k-1}{\sqrt{k}\log k}\right) \frac{\sigma_B^2 T}{\log^2 k}\right) \;\;\text{for}\;\; k=\frac{K}{F_0}.$$

[image]

**References:**

- Choi J, Kwak M, Tee CW, Wang Y (2022) **A Black–Scholes user’s guide to the Bachelier model.** *Journal of Futures Markets* 42:959–980. https://doi.org/10.1002/fut.22315. [[Arxiv Download](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.08686)]
- Grunspan C (2011) **A Note on the Equivalence between the Normal and the Lognormal Implied Volatility : A Model Free Approach.** [arXiv:11121782](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1782) [q-fin]

Answer (score 1):

This classical article by Patrick Hagan might help you:
http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/Norm%20-%20LogNorm/Hagan%20Normvol.pdf