# Libor Market Model

Tags: volatility, interest, normal

I try to simulate forward rates with the Libor Market Model (LMM). Unfortunately, I just have data for normal vols instead of lognormal vols which are assumed in the LMM. Is there a way I can adjust either the LMM or my data to bring it together?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you convert your market data, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58564 and https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/66522